# Python command-line program that generates passwords

Tags: python, python-3.x, random, console

I took my code from [this answer](https://codereview.stackexchange.com/a/285042/234107) by me, I found it useful, so I developed it further, and here is the result.

This script generates cryptographically secure passwords. The characters used by the passwords are chosen from the 94 printable ASCII characters that aren't blank characters or control characters.

The characters are split into 4 categories: 26 lowercase letters, 26 UPPERCASE letters, 10 digits and 32 punctuations. Each password must contain UPPERCASE letters, lowercase letters, and digits, with optional punctuations.

The length of the passwords is 8 to 94 inclusive if special characters are allowed, or 8 to 62 if they aren't. The passwords can contain unique characters only and also duplicates, whether passwords will contain duplicate characters is controlled by an optional argument. And the count of characters from each of the categories in the passwords are approximately the same.

---

### Code

```py
import random
import secrets
from functools import reduce
from operator import iconcat
from string import ascii_lowercase, ascii_uppercase, digits, punctuation
from typing import Generator, List

CHARSETS = (
    (ascii_lowercase, ascii_uppercase, digits),
    (ascii_lowercase, ascii_uppercase, punctuation, digits)
)

COUNTS = (
    ((3, 36), (2, 10)),
    ((4, 68), (3, 42), (2, 10))
)


def choose_charset(charset: str, number: int, unique: bool = False) -> List[str]:
    if not unique:
        return [secrets.choice(charset) for _ in range(number)]
    charset = list(charset)
    choices = []
    for _ in range(number):
        choice = secrets.choice(charset)
        choices.append(choice)
        charset.remove(choice)

    return choices


def split(number: int, symbol: bool = False) -> Generator[int, None, None]:
    for a, b in COUNTS[symbol]:
        n = max(
            2 + secrets.randbelow(
                number // a - 1
            ), number - b
        )
        number -= n
        yield n
    if number > 10:
        raise ValueError('remaining number is too big')
    yield number


def generate_password(length: int, unique: bool = False, symbol: bool = True) -> str:
    if not 8 <= length <= (62, 94)[symbol]:
        raise ValueError(
            'argument `length` should be an `int` between 8 and 94, or between 8 and 62 if symbols are not allowed')

    password = reduce(
        iconcat,
        map(
            choose_charset, CHARSETS[symbol],
            split(length, symbol), [unique]*4
        ),
        []
    )
    random.shuffle(password)
    return ''.join(password)


if __name__ == '__main__':
    import argparse
    parser = argparse.ArgumentParser(
        prog='Password_Generator',
        description='This program generates cryptographically secure passwords.'
    )
    parser.add_argument(
        'length', type=int,
        help='length of the passwords to be generated'
    )
    unique_parser = parser.add_mutually_exclusive_group(required=False)
    unique_parser.add_argument(
        '-U', '--unique', dest='unique', action='store_true',
        help='specifies passwords should contain unique characters only'
    )
    unique_parser.add_argument(
        '-NU', '--no-unique', dest='unique', action='store_false',
        help='specifies passwords should not contain unique characters only'
    )
    parser.set_defaults(unique=False)
    symbol_parser = parser.add_mutually_exclusive_group(required=False)
    symbol_parser.add_argument(
        '-S', '--symbol', dest='symbol', action='store_true',
        help='specifies passwords should contain special characters'
    )
    symbol_parser.add_argument(
        '-NS', '--no-symbol', dest='symbol', action='store_false',
        help='specifies passwords should not contain special characters'
    )
    parser.set_defaults(symbol=True)
    parser.add_argument(
        '-C', '--count', type=int, default=1,
        help='specifies the number of passwords to generate, default 1'
    )
    namespace = parser.parse_args()
    length, unique, symbol, count = [
        getattr(namespace, name) for name in ('length', 'unique', 'symbol', 'count')]

    for _ in range(count):
        print(generate_password(length, unique, symbol))
```

---

### Help message

```
PS C:\Users\Xeni> D:\MyScript\password_generator.py -h
usage: Password_Generator [-h] [-U | -NU] [-S | -NS] [-C COUNT] length

This program generates cryptographically secure passwords.

positional arguments:
  length                length of the passwords to be generated

options:
  -h, --help            show this help message and exit
  -U, --unique          specifies passwords should contain unique characters only
  -NU, --no-unique      specifies passwords should not contain unique characters only
  -S, --symbol          specifies passwords should contain special characters
  -NS, --no-symbol      specifies passwords should not contain special characters
  -C COUNT, --count COUNT
                        specifies the number of passwords to generate, default 1
```

---

### Example usage

```
PS C:\Users\Xeni> D:\MyScript\password_generator.py 16 -C 8
1o71NV8{rt*.3l4W
L533*8X1m$9`!w6R
9#0<W4~ZuK#"51Vd
V9y93Y^2B34Go71/
50]9o1]E1&ap6HU#
~42pL"46T'7633zd
6Zw1a9z"F16H7~3Z
2Ab7S<r82o7_KN49
PS C:\Users\Xeni> D:\MyScript\password_generator.py 16 -U -C 8
xt7)kG48O9KW\^0]
Pz02ac51>8_UY43g
6[kYF?0H98Oq3'21
Fp50N>P47n+369A1
9v743R0%V5\2s186
Dbr1%\0a}486TQF;
K?l1Cz;92Wn7|Z54
1a@7]4yBsCx52Y0G
PS C:\Users\Xeni> D:\MyScript\password_generator.py 16 -U -NS -C 8
c0YgQ9C54k86Ff3m
Dwd3W412059ujm8H
17pWJvhyC9b82460
Qs52409Az673R18Z
89R2Pk6z401nN73H
7gDcO30yxG54d86K
i62s1kQC89IuBb45
iw02Zn96Ez1xQY8N
```

---

As the program became sufficiently complex I wanted it to be reviewed, in particular this is the first time I have ever used `argparse`. I would like my code to be more concise and efficient.

Comment: You passed up the [opportunity](https://pypi.org/project/typer) to `import typer`. You elected to not write any """docstrings""". The identifiers `a, b` are not well chosen. There's no unit tests, and since you rely on global PRNG state there won't be. Dup suppression is an odd choice, as it reduces entropy. Choosing to suppress punctuation near start / end of password _would_ make good [UX](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Fitts%27s_law) sense, in order to make double-click copy-n-paste a little easier.

Comment: Please do not edit the question, especially the code, after an answer has been posted. Changing the question may cause answer invalidation. Everyone needs to be able to see what the reviewer was referring to. [What to do after the question has been answered.](https://codereview.stackexchange.com/help/someone-answers)

Answer (score 17, accepted):

**Put all code in functions**. Code in functions can be tested, experimented
with, and reorganized much more easily than code floating around at the top
level. Floating code introduces the temptation to rely on global variables,
which can create substantial headaches even at moderate program sizes. Putting
everything in functions forces you to think clearly about how the behavior and
data flow is organized. It's a time-tested practice worth embracing.

**Invest a lot more energy in code clarity and readability**. I started
experimenting with this code expecting to write a typical review suggesting
improvements on various details, but I was quickly overwhelmed by the
complexity and opacity of the code. A few examples. (1) What is `COUNTS`? The
constant name is generic, there are no comments to provide clues, the data
structure is is almost (but not quite) parallel to `CHARSETS`, and the numbers
themselves are not evidently self-explanatory. (2) What is the `split()`
function's purpose and behavior? Again, the name is generic and a bit puzzling
(what is being split?). There are no docstrings or comments explaining the
intent. Its logic is driven by the mystery numbers in `COUNTS`, using
completely abstract variable names of `a` and `b`. After experimenting with the
code, I get the sense that the job of `split()` is to determine how many of
each category of characters (lower, upper, digits, punctation) we will select
to build a password, but nothing in the code aids me in reaching that
determination. I had to figure that out via experimentation, printing, and
close reading. (3) What is `choose_charset()`? Are we really choosing a
character set, meaning selecting among the `CHARSETS` data? It doesn't look
like that. Is `number` in this function the same as `number` in `split()`? And
how do those generic concepts compare to password `length`? The naming scheme is
both generic and seemingly inconsistent. (4) The algorithm in
`generate_password()` is a head-scratcher. I would confidently wager than less
than 1 in 1000 experienced Python programmers have ever used `iconcat` -- which
doesn't necessarily make it a bad thing to use, but it does convey the terrain
you're walking on. After a fair bit of study, I managed to figure out what
it's doing, but you are really making your reader work hard! Consider the
following comparison. Even without improving the rest of the code's naming and
readability, we can clarify password generation a lot just by *doing the normal
Python thing* rather than by doing something super-clever.

```
# Original code: reduce, iconcat?!?, map, choose_charset -- huh?
password = reduce(
    iconcat,
    map(
        choose_charset, CHARSETS[symbol],
        split(length, symbol), [unique]*4
    ),
    []
)

# Revised code: ok, there is a tuple of "splits" (not sure what that means,
# but it's the same size as CHARSETS, so I sort of see the connection). Oh,
# and then we just build the password from the characters coming out of
# choose_charset(). I sort of get it now.
splits = tuple(split(length, symbol))
password = [
    char
    for charset, s in zip(CHARSETS[symbol], splits)
    for char in choose_charset(charset, s, unique)
]
```

**Does the code work correctly**? When I see this kind of complexity, my
suspicions are raised. How do I know the code is doing the right thing? I
decided to do some quick analysis. Thanks to your good decision to use a
command-line argument parser, I quickly added a new behavior to be triggered by
`--analysis`. It takes a bunch of passwords and counts up how often each
category of characters is observed. Here's the new function, and a sketch of
how I wove it into the existing code.

```
import sys
from collections import Counter

def main(args):
    parser = argparse.ArgumentParser(...)
    ...
    opts = parser.parse_args(args)
    ...
    if opts.analysis:
        passwords = [
            generate_password(opts.length, opts.unique, opts.symbol)
            for _ in range(count)
        ]
        analyze_passwords(opts, passwords)
    else:
        ...

def analyze_passwords(opts, passwords):
    csets = dict(
        lower = ascii_lowercase,
        upper = ascii_uppercase,
        punct = punctuation,
        digit = digits,
    )
    c = Counter(
        next(name for name, chars in csets.items() if c in chars)
        for p in passwords
        for c in p
    )
    for k in csets:
        print(k, round(c[k] / opts.count, 3))

if __name__ == '__main__':
    main(sys.argv[1:])
```

I ran the analysis across various password lengths (8, 16, 35, 70), with and
without `--unique`. The results suggest that you might want to reconsider your
approach. As password length increases, digits and especially punctuation
become over-represented, while lowercase letters are
under-represented. Also, it seems that digits are always being
selected in unique mode (or otherwise somehow capped at 10
appearances), even when the user did not specify that option on the
command line.

```text
Category | 8   | 16    | 35     | 70        # Non-unique.
----------------------------------------
lower    | 2.0 | 3.0   | 5.006  | 9.548
upper    | 2.0 | 2.983 | 5.869  | 18.794
punct    | 2.0 | 3.386 | 14.127 | 31.658
digit    | 2.0 | 6.632 | 9.998  | 10.0

Category | 8   | 16    | 35     | 70        # Unique.
-----------------------------------------
lower    | 2.0 | 2.997  | 5.007  | 9.559  
upper    | 2.0 | 3.0    | 5.857  | 18.77
punct    | 2.0 | 3.398  | 14.138 | 31.672
digit    | 2.0 | 6.606  | 9.998  | 10.0
```

**A key in the fight against complexity: well-focused data objects**. After
thinking about your program a while I decided to abandon any effort at
line-by-line or even function-by-function advice. I would suggest a complete
rethink. Rather than improving the `split()` function, for example, I would
suggest that you figure out a way not to need it at all. One way to start is by
creating a data object to represent a `CharacterSet` and the behaviors that
could be tied to it when generating passwords. Such an object should know its
universe of characters (lower, upper, digits, punctuation). It should know how
to randomly emit another character, subject to any unique constraint. And it
should know whether the next request to get another character will fail due to
that constraint.

```
class CharacterSet:

    def __init__(self, chars, unique = False):
        self.chars = chars
        self.unique = bool(unique)
        self.remaining = list(chars)
        random.shuffle(self.remaining)

    def next_char(self):
        if self.unique:
            # Because we shuffled, we can just pop from the end.
            return self.remaining.pop()
        else:
            return secrets.choice(self.chars) 

    @property
    def is_empty(self):
        return self.unique and not self.remaining
```

With that very simple data-object in place, the code to generate a single
password in a way that respects the unique constraint and (as much as possible)
selects evenly from the different character categories might look like
the following:

```
from itertools import cycle

def create_password(length, unique = False, include_punct = False):
    # Create the CharacterSet instances.
    categories = (ascii_lowercase, ascii_uppercase, digits, punctuation)
    csets = [
        CharacterSet(chars, unique)
        for chars in categories
    ]
    if not include_punct:
        csets.pop()
    random.shuffle(csets)

    # Build a password by just cycling though the shuffled
    # CharacterSet instances, getting their next character.
    password = []
    csets = cycle(csets)
    for _ in range(length):
        while True:
            cset = next(csets)
            if not cset.is_empty:
                break
        password.append(cset.next_char())
    random.shuffle(password)
    return ''.join(password)
```

**Next steps: reconsider even distributions**. When passwords generated by the
code above are run through the `analyze_passwords()` function, the passwords
end up having a very even distribution across the character categories (again,
subject to unique constraint). But you might want to reconsider having such an
even distribution. My advice would be to start with the minimum counts desired for
each category (eg, 2 characters from each category). You can build that
password in the manner shown above. Then, to get the remaining characters
needed to achieve full password length, draw from a universal `CharacterSet`
that is created using all of the remaining characters from the
category-specific `CharacterSet` instances.

Answer (score 14):

I feel like you came up with an over-engineered solution that, ultimately, fails to meet expectations.

Generating a password is a task with well-defined use-cases, that we encounter almost daily.

Most requirement come from security considerations:

1. use a cryptographically secure source of randomness
2. eliminate all identifiable patterns in generated passwords
3. don't impose a limit on password length
4. use as wide an alphabet/character set as possible

Your algorithm fails on almost all accounts.

After picking characters from different character sets, these are shuffled with `random.shuffle`, which is not crypto-grade randomness, violating the first requirement.

The algorithm over-represents digits and punctuation, as noted in FMc's great answer, violating the requirement number 2.

The `-U` option also introduces patterns, against requirement 2.

If the `-NU` option is selected, the length of the password is limited by the size of the character set for no apparent reason. You might think the length is good enough, but in fact I can't generate a password with my go-to settings (no special chars, 64-length, for good enough entropy and not having to deal with each website's different limitations for special chars). Requirement 3 failed.

The options allow either to include all printable special characters, or none of them. In fact, in the real world, you are usually limited to a subset of some special chars, but you can't use that with your solution. Requirement 4 failed.

---

Now, this set of requirements is not actually hard to meet. In fact, taking inspiration from the `secrets` module documentation's [Recipes and best practices](https://docs.python.org/3/library/secrets.html#recipes-and-best-practices), it's quite simple to come up with a simple solution:

```py
import secrets


def generate_password(length, alphabet):
    return ''.join(secrets.choice(alphabet) for _ in range(length))
```

This allows meeting all four requirements. Now, add on top some well-designed command-line switches with sensible defaults, and we actually have a usable password generator.

Comment: _Thank you_ for mentioning that limiting the number of occurrences of any particular character is _wrong_ as it decreases the number of potential passwords -- and does so drastically. As an example, imagine an 8 digits PIN code where digits have to be unique. There are... 45 distinct sets of digits that can be used. Shuffling them (8!) leads to 1.8 millions combinations. That's 50x less than the 100 millions combinations without the uniqueness requirement.

Answer (score 5):

### Another perspective: adopting legacy* code

I agree with the other answers and I would never use this code to generate passwords, since (1) it's not cryptographically secure and (2) it's highly opaque, and I don't want opaque code near security systems.  But it also has many typical features of a lot of 'legacy' code out there which we *do* want to keep using.  So let's think about adopting it as an exercise.

When you're tempted to write stuff like this:

```py
COUNTS = (
    ((3, 36), (2, 10)),
    ((4, 68), (3, 42), (2, 10))
)
```

Reach for `collections.namedtuple`.

What are these two numbers?  What roles do they play?  I don't know, and since the algorithm here isn't cryptographically secure anyway I decided not to figure it out.  But you could have told me straight out by declaring a datatype:

```py
from collections import namedtuple

Count = namedtuple("Count", "first_thing,second_thing")
COUNTS = ((Count(3, 36), Count(2,10),)
```

The best thing about this is that namedtuples are tuples, so you can bolt this on later.  You don't *have* to use property access (`Count.first_thing`).  Later on, you can go through and convert the access, but for now just declaring the type will get you instant clarity---and your IDE/editor will probably start hinting everything.  Later on we can declare a proper class if we need to.

I often do this immediately when I start reading legacy code: it's one of the lowest-cost ways to start injecting some clarity.

Of course you have to tell me what `first_thing` and `second_thing` are (or I'd have to read your code much more closely than I have time for atm).

Hang on, though, Counts is a tuple of tuples.  (Lists of lists or tuples of tuples are usually a sign that we're not using datastructures very well.)  What does it correlate to?  Oh, probably `CHARSETS`.  Well then, we should declare that correlation explicitly:

```py
CHARSETS = {
    "printable": ...,
    "all": ...,
}

COUNTS = {
    "printable": Count(...),
    "all": Count(...),
}
```

This modification isn't zero-cost, but we can still change a few lines---for  now---and replace `CHARSETS[x]` with `CHARSETS["descriptive_x"]`.

The next step, if I was adopting legacy code, would probably be to combine counts and charsets into one datatype: they *probably* belong together, although I got lost in the algorithm so I'm not sure.  Doing so is going to require another tweak, but this particular tweak---moving from index-based lookup in a bunch of lists to looking up one object and then accessing its properties---usually removes about 1/3 of the cruft in one swoop, because *usually* we're spending a lot of time generating a datastructure at runtime, and if we present the data in the right package to begin with we can just focus on the logic.  Incidentally this isn't a high-level language thing: plenty of refactoring in C consists of replacing bunches of arrays with a single array (or even a linked list) of a well designed struct.

I'll stop there as I'd have to get into the particular code and I don't think it's worth it from the cryptographic POV.

*legacy code = any code older than about 5 minutes.  I'm sure there are plenty of excellent programmers who get everything right first time, but your own code often becomes 'legacy' with a few days.